# move constructor is not getting called when I am calling constructor explicitly as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to learn about move constructors. I wrote the below program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class myclass {
    public:
        myclass() { 
            cout << "In Constructor" << endl;
        }

        ~myclass() {
            cout << "In Destructor" << endl;
        }

        myclass(const myclass &obj) {
            cout << "In Copy Constructor" << endl;
        }

        myclass(myclass &&obj) {
            cout << "In Move Constructor" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    myclass obj = myclass();       // Line 1
    myclass obj(myclass());        // Line 2
}
```

Line 1 is working as expected, move constructor is getting called if I use '-fno-elide-constructors' flag.
But for line 2, nothing is happening. Not even constructor is getting called. I thought that move constructor will be called for line 2 also. But no function is getting called. I know if I call the constructor explicitly, the object will be destroyed at the end of the expression. But I am not sure why even constructor is not getting called. Can any one please let me know what is wrong with Line 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example of the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse); `obj` is declared to be a function, rather than an object of type `myclass`. Most instances of the most vexing parse can be avoided by changing one (or both) pairs of parentheses to braces. For example:

```
myclass obj(myclass{});
```

Note that even in C++11, the compiler [may optimize out the move](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/412ebb1d69bed8c5) (with both direct-initialization and copy-initialization). In C++17, the move is guaranteed to not occur; the object will simply be value-initialized.

Comment: FYI: please enable the compiler warning for this! (And promote it to error), you really never need it to become function declaration